# Display Image On WPF DataGrid With Autogenerated Columns

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have image stored in MySQL database, recently I'm moving to VB WPF from win forms.

I've read through questions regarding this issue, non satisfied me.
How do I set a column to display image instead of byte array , when the column is auto generated.

The column name will be unspecified, the column index is not specified.

Can some one point me with a clear explanation if I have to use a template , how it would be?

Please don't point me to other links, as I found no useful answer for me.

Any help will be much appreciated

Extra information on my grid :

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
            <DataGrid
                x:Name="DataGrid1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                SelectionMode="Extended"
                SelectionUnit="Cell" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer will help some one , without using converter etc

Basically, by handling the autogeneratingcolumn events, you can set and format the value. Assuming all byte array on the database is image, otherwise extra condition should be implemented (columname etc).

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.AutoGeneratingColumn
        Dim column As DataGridTextColumn = TryCast(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
        If e.PropertyType = GetType(System.Byte()) Then
            Try
                Dim img As New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(Image))
                img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, New Binding(e.PropertyName))
                e.Column = New DataGridTemplateColumn With {
                    .CellTemplate = New DataTemplate() With {
                        .VisualTree = img
                    },
                    .Header = ""}
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
        If e.PropertyType = GetType(System.DateTime) Then
            column.Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"
        End If
        If e.PropertyType = GetType(System.UInt32) Or e.PropertyType = GetType(System.Decimal) Then
            column.Binding.StringFormat = "#,###0"
        End If
    End Sub
```